# flutter tutorialcoachmark wrong position

Tags: flutter

I'm have 3 target of this tutorial, in second and third tutorial is working normally, but in first target of tutorial have wrong position. I tried in 2 android device and it's work normally, but I tried in other android device have wrong position of circle highlight like this, the circle must be in my red mark at top right.

the key have wrong position is `keyEditButton`

NOTE : `ketEditButton` (first target) and `keySaveButton` (third target) is have same position, `keySaveButton` have a nice position, but `keyEditButton is not`

[image]

this my code

```
void initState() {
  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, showTutorial);
}



void showTutorial() {
    tutorialON = true;
    initTargets();
    tutorialCoachMark = TutorialCoachMark(
      context,
      targets: targets,
      colorShadow: const Color(0xFF061988),
      textSkip: "SKIP",
      paddingFocus: 10,
      opacityShadow: 0.8,
      onFinish: () {
        // print("finish");
        tutorialON = false;
        categoriesTutorialPreference(true);
      },
      onClickTarget: (target) {
        // print('onClickTarget: $target');
        
      },
      onClickOverlay: (target) {
        print('onClickOverlay: $target');
      },
      onSkip: () {
        
      },
    )..show();
  }

void initTargets() {
    targets.clear();
    targets.add(
      TargetFocus(
        identify: "keyEditButton",
        keyTarget: keyEditButton,
        alignSkip: Alignment.topLeft,
        enableOverlayTab: false,
        contents: [
          TargetContent(
            align: ContentAlign.bottom,
            builder: (context, controller) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Klik untuk edit urutan kategori",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: textHeader2
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    targets.add(
      TargetFocus(
        identify: "keyCategoriesContainer",
        keyTarget: keyCategoriesContainer,
        alignSkip: Alignment.topLeft,
        enableOverlayTab: false,
        contents: [
          TargetContent(
            align: ContentAlign.bottom,
            builder: (context, controller) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "klik dan tahan untuk menggeser urutan kategori",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: textHeader2
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    targets.add(
      TargetFocus(
        identify: "keySaveButton",
        keyTarget: keySaveButton,
        alignSkip: Alignment.topLeft,
        enableOverlayTab: false,
        contents: [
          TargetContent(
            align: ContentAlign.bottom,
            builder: (context, controller) {
              return Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Klik untuk keluar dari proses edit kategori",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: textHeader2
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

this how I add the key of this lib

```
appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Palette.color_primary,
          title: const Text("Categories", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                key: edit ? keySaveButton : keyEditButton,  // <- this key
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      if (edit) {
                        btnEdit = "Edit";
                        icon = const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.pen);
                        edit = false;
                      } else {
                        btnEdit = "Done";
                        icon = const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.check);
                        edit = true;
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [icon],
                  ),
                )),
          ],
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.white, //change your color here
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 8):

Add more delays. It happens because showTutorial called when page is not fully rendered. Below, worked for me.

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), showTutorial);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, it was the animation of the PageRoute. Right after the SplashScreen, the tutorial starts with a wrong TargetPosition because the animation of the Route object was not finished yet.

If you have a similar scenario. Try this:

Instead of:

```js
Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()),
    );
```

try:

```js
Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) => const HomeScreen(),
        transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
      ),
    );
```

If you want this animation, you either need to add an appropriate delay before the tutorial starts or the more consistent solution would be to find out when the animation is finished.

You should also consider calling showTutorial after the rendering has been completed:

```js
void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((value) {
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, showTutorial);
    });
  }
```